# How to find and click a JavaScript button by aria-label with Python Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, automation

I am trying to use Python Selenium to find a certain javascript button on a page and click it. Before, you click away or link to another page, the other solutions on the forums don't apply to my situation. First, I'll show an image of the page full of buttons. **I am trying to click on the button called "Schoology".**

[image: This is the array of buttons on the site, I am trying to click the button called "Schoology"]

Next, I'll go ahead and show the outer HTML code of the certain button I am trying to click -

`<application _ngcontent-bxy-c60 tabindex="0" role="link" class="cl-app app-margin ng-star-inserted" _nghost-bxy-c57 aria-label="Schoology">`

Here's a screenshot if its easier to read.

[image]

The Schoology button I want to click is in JavaScript. After using the Web Driver Wait function with `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located` to ensure I'm on the correct page, I went ahead to try to click the button. There are a few things I tried, but they failed

**1. Finding the element using XPATH**

`driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByXpath('/html/body/app-root/secure/div/app-apps-container/application[8]').click()")`.

This resulted in a `document.getElementByXpath is not a function` error.

**2. Finding the element using class name**

`driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('cl-app app-margin ng-star-inserted')[0].click()")`

The issue here is that each one of the JavaScript buttons has the same exact class. When I used this line of code, the script executed and clicked the first button (AP Human Geography) instead of the Schoology button I wanted.

**Is there a way to do this using the Aria-Label?**

I noticed that the Aria-Label does distinguish and identify each JavaScript button. In my case, where it says `"aria-label = "Schoology"`. However, I'm not sure how this would be implemented. How can I use something such as the Aria-Label to make sure the script clicks on the correct JavaScript button. Please keep in mind that I need to do this in a way such that the script doesn't choose the wrong button (i.e Clicking the first button because all of them have the same class name)

Here is a screenshot of the inner HTML code in case that would be a better way to approach the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//application[@aria-label='Schoology']//button")
```

You can use it's xpath and data attribute. I am assuming you need to click on its button tag. If not remove the //button.

Answer (score 0):

The way of doing this using selectors would be to enter the following query:

```
application[aria-label$="Schoology"]
```

Or you can use XPath:

```
//application[@aria-label="Schoology"]
```